# Find multiple files with unique file names and move them

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2008-r2

Im looking to get some helt creating a BAT file.
I do not have a lot of knowledge about this from before.

The situation:
I have a folder containing about 48 000 pdf files.
I have a csv file containing all the file names (aprox 15000 unique file names) i want to separate and move to another folder.

The files are named like this: 0723850734;0732332262;0723846680;0736187285;0733628507.... and so on.

I created this .BAT file to copy one file:

copy /-y "D:\Scrive\Data\Done\PDF\0723850734.pdf" "D:\Scrive\Data\Done\Telenoravtal"

pause

How can i add all my file names i want to copy/move?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a hack or a workaround than a real solution.

You can open the `.csv` file in Excel and create template using first part of your code in Column A and drag it as far as you need then in Column B having the file name and in Column C having the rest of your code.

```
_____________Column A _____________|__Column B__|______________Column C____________________
copy /-y "D:\Scrive\Data\Done\PDF\ | 0723850734 | .pdf" "D:\Scrive\Data\Done\Telenoravtal"
copy /-y "D:\Scrive\Data\Done\PDF\ | 0000000000 | .pdf" "D:\Scrive\Data\Done\Telenoravtal"
copy /-y "D:\Scrive\Data\Done\PDF\ | 1234567890 | .pdf" "D:\Scrive\Data\Done\Telenoravtal"
copy /-y "D:\Scrive\Data\Done\PDF\ | 0987654321 | .pdf" "D:\Scrive\Data\Done\Telenoravtal"
```

Afterwords just copy the results to text editor, remove extra spaces and your bat script is done.